Scale mean pairwise cosine distance between 0 and 1
I’m trying to obtain a min-max normalized version of the mean pairwise cosine distance for  vectors.
When calculating the mean pairwise cosine distance between two vectors (which is actually not a mean because it's only a single distance for a single pair), the maximum possible distance is 2 if the vectors are perfectly orthogonal. However, as the number of vectors increases, achieving perfect orthogonality among all pairs becomes impossible. For instance, with three vectors, the maximum "mean pairwise cosine distance" I’ve observed is around 1.5, and for four vectors, it’s approximately 1.333, and so on.
In my current implementation, I use a computationally intensive function called generate_most_orthogonal_vectors to estimate this upper bound for normalization purposes. However, I’m wondering if there’s a simpler mathematical formula I could use to determine this upper bound, which would allow me to avoid the heavy computation.
Maybe the answer is no, there is no such formula. In that case, the only possibility I have would be to precompute these bounds before and re-use them when executing my code.
import math
import itertools
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

def similarity(vector1, vector2):
    """Range between -1 and 1."""
    magnitude1 = math.sqrt(sum(x * x for x in vector1))
    magnitude2 = math.sqrt(sum(x * x for x in vector2))
    if magnitude1 == 0 or magnitude2 == 0:
        return 0.0
    return sum(x * y for x, y in zip(vector1, vector2)) / (magnitude1 * magnitude2)

def distance(vector1, vector2):
    """Range between 0 and 2."""
    return 1 - similarity(vector1, vector2)

def pairwise_distance(vectors):
    """Range between 0 and 2 (in theory, 2 cannot be reached for len(vectors) > 2)."""
    return np.mean([distance(a, b) for a, b in itertools.combinations(vectors, 2)])

def generate_most_orthogonal_vectors(n, dim=2, tol=1e-6, max_iter=10000, max_vectors=100_000):
    # Randomly initialize points on the hypersphere (n random vectors):
    n_random_vectors = n * 500 * dim
    if n_random_vectors > max_vectors:
        n_random_vectors = max_vectors
    random_vectors = np.random.randn(n_random_vectors, dim)
    random_vectors = normalize(random_vectors)  # Normalize to make unit vectors
    # Use KMeans to find the most spread out cluster centers:
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n, tol=tol, max_iter=max_iter, n_init=10)
    kmeans.fit(random_vectors)
    # The cluster centers will serve as our orthogonal vectors:
    vectors = kmeans.cluster_centers_
    return normalize(vectors)  # Ensure they remain unit vectors

def pairwise_distance_upper_bound(n, dim):
    """
    In theory the upper bound depends on the number of vectors `n` and maybe
    the number of dimensions `dim`. It can be find by computing the pairwise
    cosine distance of uniformly spaced vectors on a hypersphere. For example,
    in a 2-dimensional space, the optimal configuration is an equilateral
    triangle.
    """
    return round(pairwise_distance(generate_most_orthogonal_vectors(n, dim)), 3)

def normalized_pairwise_distance(vectors):
    """Range between 0 and 1 (1 can be reached in theory whatever the number of vectors)."""
     # Assuming `dim` does not change the result:
    return pairwise_distance(vectors) / pairwise_distance_upper_bound(len(vectors))


So from what I understand, you want to compute $$\sup\left{\frac12{k\choose2}^{-1}\sum_{v,w\in S\v\ne w}\left(1-\frac{v\cdot w}{|v||w|}\right) \quad\middle\vert\quad S\subset\mathbb R^3,:|S|=k\right}$$ for fixed $k\in\mathbb N$?

Thx for your answer but I did not manage to have the right upper bounds using your formula. I think I was unclear in my post, I re-wrote it with a complete demo.

I'm not sure what you mean "using my formula"; what I've written is not an algorithm, its a description of what you want using math notation, and I don't consider it an answer to the question. From reading your question again, I am fairly confident it is accurate.

"the maximum possible distance is 2 if the vectors are perfectly orthogonal" This is false; the maximum of 2 is attained when the vectors are parallel but pointing in opposite directions.

Right I did not get that, thx for the notation, seems correct indeed.

Let $s(v,w) = 1 - \frac{v\cdot w}{|v||w|}$ be the cosine similarity. Notice that for $v,w$ unit vectors the (squared) distance between them is $$|v-w|^2 = |v|^2 + |w|^2 - 2v\cdot w = 2s(v,w).$$ Thus the problem is equivalent to the following: For fixed $k \in \mathbb N$, what is the greatest value achievable by summing all pairwise distances between $k$ unit vectors?

Yes, correct. Then my first question would be: is it possible (for such math problems) to analytically find a formula defining that "greatest value"? Or do we necessarly need to find an estimation using an iterative algorithm like in my answer below.

Something else to note is that if we have $k-1$ unit vectors $v_i$ already, then the optimal $k^{\text{th}}$ unit vector is exactly $$v_k = -V/|V|,\quad V=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}v_i.$$ Notice that we can also reason backward like this: given $k$ unit vectors that achieve the maximal average, it must be that $V$ is constrained as above.

We could turn this into $kn$ quadratic equations in $kn$ unkowns, where $n$ is the dimension. If $v_{ij}$ is the $j^{\text{th}}$ component of $v_i$, then a set of unit vectors with maximal average must satisfy $$\left[\sum_l\left(\sum_{m\ne i}v_{ml}\right)^2\right]v_{ij} + \sum_{m\ne i}v_{mj} = 0$$ for all $i,j$.

Suggesting an answer that is not really satisfying (it's not a proper formula but a power law estimation), it's better than nothing though.
def pairwise_distance_upper_bound(n, a=2.8550230934074574, b=-1.5986905003667868, c=1.047364845041582, d=-0.007355035060315269):
    return a * n**b + c * n**d

I got this estimation using this code:
import random
from tqdm import tqdm
import pickle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
data = {}
xs = list(range(2, 1000))
random.shuffle(xs)
for x in tqdm(xs): # You can stop that loop when you want, then save data (it is not necessary to generate all points)
    if x not in data:
        data[x] = pairwise_distance(generate_most_orthogonal_vectors(x))
with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)
with open("data.pickle", "rb") as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
points = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda row: row[0])
class PowerLawFitter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parameters = None
        self.r_squared = None
    # Define the flexible power-law function: y = a * x^b + d * x^e
    def flexible_power_law(self, x, a, b, d, e):
        return a * np.power(x, b) + d * np.power(x, e)
    # Fit the model to the provided data
    def fit(self, data):
        # Extract x and y values from the data
        x_vals, y_vals = zip(*data)
        x = np.array(x_vals)
        y = np.array(y_vals)
        # Fit the flexible power law to the data
        try:
            # Provide reasonable initial guesses: (a=1, b=1, d=1, e=1)
            popt, _ = curve_fit(self.flexible_power_law, x, y, p0=(1, 1, 1, 1), maxfev=1000000)
            self.parameters = popt
            # Compute the fitted y values using the optimized parameters
            y_fit = self.flexible_power_law(x, *self.parameters)
            # Calculate R-squared to evaluate the goodness of fit
            self.r_squared = r2_score(y, y_fit)
            # Print the results
            print(f"Optimized parameters: a = {self.parameters[0]:.6f}, b = {self.parameters[1]:.6f}, "
                  f"d = {self.parameters[2]:.6f}, e = {self.parameters[3]:.6f}")
            print(f"R-squared: {self.r_squared:.6f}")
            return self.parameters, self.r_squared
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Flexible power-law fitting failed: {e}")
            return None
    # Transform new x values using the fitted model
    def transform(self, x_new):
        if self.parameters is None:
            raise ValueError("The model has not been fitted yet. Please call the fit() method first.")
        return self.flexible_power_law(np.array(x_new), *self.parameters)
    # Plot the fitted model along with the data
    def plot(self, data):
        x_vals, y_vals = zip(*data)
        x = np.array(x_vals)
        y = np.array(y_vals)
        if self.parameters is None:
            print("Model parameters are not set. Please fit the model first.")
            return
        # Compute the fitted y values
        y_fit = self.flexible_power_law(x, *self.parameters)
        # Plot the data and the fitted curve
        plt.scatter(x, y, label="Data Points")
        plt.plot(x, y_fit, color='red', label=f"Flexible Power-Law Fit: $y = "
                  f"{self.parameters[0]:.2f} x^{self.parameters[1]:.2f} + "
                  f"{self.parameters[2]:.2f} x^{self.parameters[3]:.2f}$")
        plt.legend()
        plt.xlabel("X")
        plt.ylabel("Y")
        plt.title(f"Flexible Power-Law Fit (R-squared: {self.r_squared:.6f})")
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()
# Create an instance of the PowerLawFitter class
fitter = PowerLawFitter()
# Fit the model to the data
parameters, r_squared = fitter.fit(points)
# Plot the fitted model
fitter.plot(points)
# Try on some examples:
for n in [2, 3, 4, 10, 100, 1000]:
    print(fitter.transform(n))
print(f"a={fitter.parameters[0]}, b={fitter.parameters[1]}, c={fitter.parameters[2]}, d={fitter.parameters[3]}")


